# ffmpeg stops exporting images when using overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, preview

I am using ffmpeg to stream first 35 seconds of a movie over udp ..
in the process of showing a preview of this movie while streaming i reached this command

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -t 00:00:35.000 -i input.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1200:720[scaled];[1:v]scale=150:-1[overl],[scaled][overl]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10[logo]" -map "[logo]" -map 0:a -c:a copy  -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.1:1234 -vf fps=4 -s 320x240 -update 1 -y preview.jpg
```

the problem is .. if i don't use the overlay i get my preview.jpg perfectly, but when i do .. ffmpeg streams ok but without creating the jpg image ..

any idea ?? please.

thank you.

Comment: Do you want the preview with the overlay?

Comment: Yes and with all the applied filters like subtitle and banner and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final processed stream has to be cloned and mapped, so for the given command,

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -t 00:00:35.000 -i input.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1200:720[scaled];[1:v]scale=150:-1[overl];[scaled][overl]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,split=2[logo][preview];[preview]fps=4,scale=320x240[preview]" -map "[logo]" -map 0:a -c:a copy  -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.1:1234 -map "[preview]" -update 1 -y preview.jpg
```

(The issue corrected here has nothing to do with the updating of a single image).